# Is DC voltage gain the change in offset and AC voltage gain the change in amplitude of the input waveform?

Tags: gain

I can't find an explanation on this site or elsewhere that addresses this concept as directly/simply as I suspect is possible, surprisingly. Maybe I'm a bad searcher, but it's not for lack of trying.

I made two graphs demonstrating what I currently interpret DC gain and AC gain to mean.

[image]

That is, DC gain affects the offset of the waveform and AC affects the amplitude of the waveform.

Is my understanding correct? If not, I'd greatly appreciate an explanation of the difference at a similar level to this (if possible).

(This question and diagram is not 'homework'; I'm just trying to understand an introductory level concept.)

Comment: This usually relates to the frequency domain.  Your first diagram relates to (DC) offset shift and the second is gain change.  As your signal has majority AC component and no real DC component we cannot infer the DC gain/change.  The DC gain is the gain that occurs with signals at 0Hz (or some agreed small number).  This correlates in certain cases with large and small signal gain if you have a DC offset with small variation.

Comment: Ahh! Awesome. Your comment and Felthry's answer have clarified this greatly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. The two gains are exactly the same thing, in truth; the ratio of output signal to input signal. If DC and AC gains are given separately, that implies that some filtering is present, in order to attenuate signals at unwanted frequencies, or just as a consequence of the parasitic elements that are due to the circuit geometry. AC gain can be read as being the output over the input when the operating frequency is high, and DC gain is output over input when operating frequency is low.

Comment: Thank you very much! In that case, is there some distinction like that the DC gain is unaffected by filtering but the AC gain is? (This would be consistent with my understanding of capacitance, parasitic or otherwise.) Are there any circumstances/circuits for which AC gain is greater than DC gain?

Comment: @user3949312  In any 'AC' coupled amplifier it is assumed that DC gain is supressed and only AC gain is of interest.  Audio circuits are a prime example.  Though as the professional nature of the audio grows so the low frequencies get additional consideration (but not all the way to 0Hz as this just burns speakers and has no sound value).